# What is an undirected graph with cost and reverse cost?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

What is the purpose of a graph that is "undirected, with cost and reverse cost"?
Where is the difference to a graph that is "undirected, with cost" ?

For me it does not really make sense, because for my understanding the reverse cost should just come into play when the graph is directed ... 
(Figure from http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/doc/src/developer/sampledata.html#fig2)
[image: graph that is undirected, with cost and reverse cost]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can set undirected graph with reverse_cost has a simple reason: the function has two arguments, one for `directed` true/false and one for `reverse_cost` true/false. But you're right that it only makes sense for a directed graph. In the other case it will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the documentation at http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/dijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-dijkstra can shed some light onto the isse. It would seem like - in an undirected graph - one can go in either direction with either cost or reverse_cost:

[image]

Not sure which real-world application this is used for though.

Comment: Not tried this myself, but [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/114786/55203) suggests a couple of practical applications for this and gives an example.